# Targeting blank spaces in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a hangman-like game. Basically let's say I have a secret word, like, *"beauty and the beast"* and it's up to the user to guess the letters and ultimately the whole word.

So far my code works fine, but if you want to check it out anyway [here you go](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/VGGHZNcEc2vAc5gHxOMR/). Here is the relevant portion:

```
def draw(good_guesses, bad_guesses, secret_word):  # DRAW spaces, letters & strikes
    clear()
    print(secret_word)
    # printing strikes first
    print("Strikes: {}/7".format(len(bad_guesses)))
    print("")

    # printing bad guesses so far
    for letter in bad_guesses:
        print(letter, end=" ")  # have a space between each element
    print("\n")  # double blank lines

    # print discovered/undiscovered letters
    for letter in secret_word:
        if letter in good_guesses:
            print(letter, end=" ")
        else:
            print('_', end=" ")
    print('')
```

Back to our example though. For the string *"beauty and the beast"*, user will see printed out for him the following:

"_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _"

As you can see, the spaces of the string are printed out as underscores, and that's precisely what I'd like to change.

It would be much better if this was printed out instead:

"_ _ _ _ _ _ / _ _ _ / _ _ _ / _ _ _ _ _"

I'm thinking maybe there's a way to target blank spaces and print them out as spaces instead of underscores? Can't figure how to do that though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the logic of your code, you need to handle that case with an equality operator: `==`. So something like this would work:

```
for letter in secret_word:
    if letter in good_guesses:
        print(letter, end=" ")
    elif letter == ' ':
        print('/', end=" ")
    else:
        print('_', end=" ")

print('')
```

Comment: This is definitely the best answer to your literal question.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is change line 40 to the following:

```
if letter in good_guesses or letter == ' ':
```

Alternately, you can tack on characters to `good_guesses`:

```
if letter in good_guesses + ' ':
```

This allows you to add other characters, too:

```
if letter in good_guesses + ' -,': # Commas, spaces, and dashes are "given" to the player.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a number of improvements to your code, mostly by using `str.join` and comprehensions.

Here is a `draw` function that does what your original does, but with the requested changes and some other modifications:

```
def draw(good_guesses, bad_guesses, secret_word):
    # DRAW spaces, letters & strikes
    clear()
    print(secret_word)
    # printing strikes first
    print("Strikes: {}/7\n".format(len(bad_guesses)))

    # printing bad guesses so far
    print("{}\n".format('  '.join(bad_guesses)))

    # print discovered/undiscovered letters
    print("{}\n".format(''.join(letter if letter in good_guesses else '/' if letter == ' ' else '_' for letter in secret_word)))
```

`'  '.join(bad_guesses)` has the advantage over the original `for` loop that it does not print a trailing space.

`''.join(letter if letter in good_guesses else '/' if letter == ' ' else '_' for letter in secret_word)` joins all the elements of an iterator with the empty string. The iterator returns the letter if it was guessed correctly, `'/'` for spaces, and `'_'` for everything else.

In both cases, pre-formatting the string makes it unnecessary to use custom line endings in `print`.

Here is a sample output for your input string where the user guessed all the vowels:

```
>>> draw('aeuy', 'io', 'beauty and the beast')
beauty and the beast
Strikes: 2/7

i  o

_eau_y/a__/__e/_ea__
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've been getting confused by the .join() and .split() methods lately. Your solution although I've been avoiding one-liners... maybe it's time for me to start using them.

Comment: Actually now that I'm trying it, it seems to have altered the behavior of the program.

Comment: Underscore aren't getting drawn for some reason.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yup, as far as I can tell. Running this in terminal with python3 command.